# Get someone else's instagram stories

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

I need to get an instagram user stories and add them to my app.
I've searched a lot and didn't find any way to do such.
I tried to search it on instagram api and facebook graph api but it seems that they provide only own user data after the user is logged in.
How can i achieve that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately this is not possible with the official Instagram Graph API.